# Need help personalizing my CSS navbar: how do I highlight the <li> element on mouseover?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-selectors

I am trying to make a simple navbar I managed to make the base but when I try to personalize I am getting stuck.

My objective is that when the mouse goes over each element(home, etc) it highlights like a box, but currently it only highlights the `<a>` I tried and not the `<li>` holding it.

I'm trying to make the `<li>` an anchor that can be clicked and highlighted similar to stack's navbar.

```css
.nav-top {
  background: rgb(151, 138, 63);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav-item {
  list-style: none;
  margin-right: 1.2rem;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.nav-top ul {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none
}

.nav-top li:hover {
  display: block
}

.nav-top a:hover {
  background: #F2F2F2;
  color: #444444;
}

.nav-item a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  width: 100px;
}

.nav-item:first-child {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: 2rem;
}

.nav-item a:hover {
  color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<navbar>
  <ul class="nav-top">
    <li class="nav-item"><label class="logo">LoremX</label></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item" id="contact"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</navbar>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only `:hover` declaration you have for `li` is the default value of `display: block` while the color change declarations are made only for `a`. However, the effect that I believe you are trying to achieve is better accomplished by making the anchors block-level with padding.

Not related to the hover effect, just correcting your markup:

- You have `.nav-top ul` selector but the example doesn't include a nested `ul`
- I suspect that you are misusing the [`label`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) element.
- `navbar` is not an HTML element and I suspect you want [`nav`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nav)

```css
.nav-top {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  background: rgb(151, 138, 63);
}

.logo {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: 2rem;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  align-self: center;
}

.nav-item {
  margin-right: 1.2rem;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.nav-item a {
  display: block;
  padding: .5em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.nav-item a:hover {
  color: aqua;
  background: #F2F2F2;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="nav-top">
    <li class="logo">LoremX</li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item" id="contact"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul> 
</nav>
```

Comment: Amazing, exactly what I was trying to achieve. But I still dont get why I did notice when using the inpect that it became the whole <li>. Still not sure what  defines the "rectangle" space around it. Is the flex?

Comment: @Jonathan I looked back at my answer and am embarrassed that I focused on simply answering your question about li:hover without suggesting how the desired hover effect should be achieved. I edited my answer to show making the anchor a padded block.

Answer (score 1):

just add padding and a border in an anchor element

```
.nav-item a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```